# Rail and railing (difference)

Tags: meaning

1. Hold on to the rail.
2. Hold on to the railing.

What's the difference between rail and railing?

Comment: In your context, probably there is no difference. In *some* contexts you might be more likely to use ***railing*** to refer to an entire assembly (consisting of multiple rails and supporting posts), but this isn't a distinction the average native speaker would give any thought to.

Answer (score 1):

When used as a noun, in your example, both *rail* and *railing* has no significant difference.

> ***[rail](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rail)*** (noun)
>
> 1. a bar of wood or metal fixed horizontally for any of various purposes, as for a support, barrier, fence, or railing.
> 2. a fence; railing.
>
> (there are 5 other definitions too)
>
> ***[railing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/railing)*** (noun)
>
> 1. a fencelike barrier composed of one or more horizontal rails supported by widely spaced uprights; balustrade.
> 2. banister.
> 3. rails collectively.

By definition, a rail is an integral part of a railing. But there is also a definition that implies rail can be used to mean railing too. They are used interchangeably under the given context.

Comment: We don't actually *know* the exact context of OP's citation. Perhaps it's two parents speaking to a child. Where one might have used #2 *(railing)*, but the other corrected / clarified using #1 *(Don't hold on to the upright post that's part of the **railing**; hold on to the horizontal **rail** running between the posts)*